# How to create an asynchronous repository with EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to abstract EF Core with a repository and can't figure out how to make it asynchronous.
This is the synchronous version:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private DbSet<User> users;
    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        users = context.Set<User>();
    }
    public IQueryable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return users;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that in order to make the query asynchronous, we need to use the special extension methods from EF like `ToListAsync()` or `CountAsync()`, and if the project that uses the repository references EF namespaces, what's the point of the abstraction?

Another thing I looked into was returning `IAsyncEnumerable<User>`, and then using [this official library](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) to use LINQ asynchronously. However, I couldn't get it to behave properly because when using these new LINQ methods, the query is processed in .NET rather than converting the LINQ syntax to SQL. Let's take the following query as an example:

```
var result = await Repository.GetAll()
    .Limit(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

When using EF's extension methods, I saw this query in SSMS:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Deleted], [u].[EmailAddress], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[Status], [u].[VerifiedEmailAddress], [u].[VerifiedPhoneNumber]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=10
```

Meaning only 10 records will be selected from the DB, which is what I wanted.

But when using `System.Linq.Async`'s extension methods, I still got the same result back to my C# code, but this query showed in SSMS:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Deleted], [u].[EmailAddress], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[Status], [u].[VerifiedEmailAddress], [u].[VerifiedPhoneNumber]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
```

No limit at all, meaning if I had millions of rows in the Users table, all of them would be selected every time I run the query, when I only need the first 10.

Is there a way to work with LINQ to SQL and async streams? Or maybe another idea of how to abstract EF but still allow async querying?

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend abstracting EFCore, 
you can abstract the context using an `IApplicationDbContext`.
Mostly because EF is already an abstract layer and secondly because leaving 'users' access to the IQueryable could create unexpected behavior or exceptions.

If you really need to do this, what I am thinking about is something like:

```cs
public Task<List<User>> GetAsync(Action<IQueryable<User>> filter)
{
    filter(_users);
    return _users.ToListAsync();
}
```

and using it like:

```cs
var result = await Repository.GetAsync(x => x.Take(10));
```

Comment: I tried doing something similar, I think you have to use a `Func` that returns `IQueryable` because `Take` does not change the original object. But the main problem I have with this approach is that it only works for `ToListAsync` and that means I'll also have to create a method that calls `SumAsync` and `MaxAsync` and essentially recreate the whole LINQ interface...

Comment: But how would you like to use this then? I don't understand. If you add an interface for the context you literally abstract EF Core. And about the ToListAsync, that is just an extension method, you can create you own ToListAsync. You need to use IQueryable, so every method that enumerate the query will do the job.

Comment: Not exactly, this is not an abstraction because the interface will declare properties of type `DbSet` and that is still data access code inside of application code.

Comment: And about the extension methods, I'm order to reimplemented them I have to reference EF. That's why I prefer to put them in the repository and have that call EF instead, buts there is no much difference in implementing them with regular methods or extension methods

Comment: Got it. But unfortunately I don't know how you can do that. I still don't get why you need to do that. You want to expose the IQueryable, without knowing who is going to convert that into a call, but when using this repository you have to code like you are using EF Core otherwise you cannot be sure that the specific extension method is supported by the unknown ORM. What I used to see and work with is something like SqlUserRepository, CosmosUserRepository, MongoUserRepository etc. Sorry if this hasn't been helpful